# angular2 how to pass an object data between two components via route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Considering that I have two components X and Y.

in Component X is have this method:

```
navigate(){
  this.router.navigate(['Y', {id: this.user.id}]);
}
```

I have also defined this route:

```
{ path: 'Y/:id', component: Y }
```

What i need is to pass is the whole "user" object from component X to Y, not only it's ID..
Does the same scheme works here?
if yes, is it an engineered solution to show the whole "user" object stringified in the url?

What I need to implement is a preview page in which the user can preview his entries before finally sumbitting them to the server, while the entries are taken on wizard steps..

P.S: I've seen solutions such as using a service or resovlers but they don't seem to be suitable for my case.

Comment: A shared service is the way to go https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service, passing the whole object is an anti-pattern

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer,
But what if the preview component wasn't a child of the data entry wizard component..but rather a standalone one accessed via it's route..

honestly i don't even understand why would I need this service with a parent-child scenario since I can store the object at the parent level and share it with its children..

Comment: Did you get the relation to "parent-child" from the paragraph title in the link I posted? That title is quite misleading. A service is the preferred or only option if the components are **not** parent-child.

Comment: I understand you, but according to the first comment of this post:
https://daveceddia.com/sharing-data-between-controllers-best-practice-use-a-service/
"This is a very bad approach.
Since services are singleton the data/state will remain stored also after the directives will be destroyed. If you will heavy rely on such mechanism in a big application you will face a lot of memory leaks" 
In the link you posted they said: no memory leak would occur because of the parent-child scenario they are demonstrating, since the service provided at parent scope won't be persisted as a global singleton

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough details to give a more concrete answer. 
You can use a more generic shared service where you care yourself to remove unused values. You can have a shared service that only provides a single `Observable` everyone can use to emit events and listen to events and use it as a service bus. You also can provide the service on a common ancestor of the 2 components that want to communicate, then the service instance is limited to the lifetime of this component, and both descendants will still get the same instance injected.

Comment: Thank you so much @GünterZöchbauer
I will check all of your suggestions, but can we conclude our discussion by the fact that there is no direct way to transfer one object from one component to another through a route without any third party? I assumed that optional route parameters may help as in the official documentation they said: "it is preferred for scenarios with complex route parameters".. Thanks a lot for your help anyway!

Comment: AFAIK there is no good way to pass non-string values using the router. A shared service is almost always the answer in Angular2 except when the components are direct parent-child.

Comment: Thumbs up .. :)